# Composer installs new project in root folder

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, composer-php, symfony4

i connect via terminal to my ubuntu server with my root account.
I want to install symfony project. 
My problem is, that this installs in my /root folder. But i want to install the project in the /var/html/ folder.

How must i do this?

TELLO

Comment: Hi @M.F.! Unfortunately this question does not seem to be about programming, so it is off-topic and will probably be closed.

Comment: Use `cd /var/html`?

Comment: @rje installing symfony project I think is about programming. Otherwise where should this question be asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to composer manual:

```
-d, --working-dir=WORKING-DIR
          If specified, use the given directory as working directory.
```

BUT if you're using Symfony installer (as described in https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) then:

`composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton /var/html`

should do nicely

However! ubuntu default www root  dir is: /var/www/html/ , not /var/html so check that first.